# Soundcloud: Is there a way to upload a file via HTML and JS?

Tags: javascript, html, api, file-upload, soundcloud

Does anyone know if there's a way to upload a file that a user selects (typical HTML-based file input tag) without the current limitation in the SoundCloud API (which seems to be limited to recording local audio)?

I implemented something similar with Vimeo's API which goes something like this:

1. Get access token to avoid having to use OAuth or require a user to be a Soundcloud user to upload to my account.
2. Post a request to the API to get an upload token and URL.
3. Do an HTTP PUT against the upload URL with the file the user selected using HTML5's File API - Note this requires the user to accept the request via headers.
4. Check upload status (in Vimeo's case, you just re-PUT without data but with the ticket Id which is in the upload URL).
5. When done, make another API call to finish the process and trigger transcoding.

I'm essentially trying to enable user uploads of audio files and just send the file itself directly to Soundcloud an my account there rather than uploading to my servers and essentially doubling the work by uploading from my server to Soundcloud's.

I see that the SoundCloud JS Api supports PUTs for other tasks. I don't mind manually doing the XHR/Ajax calls directly (I'm using jQuery.ajax) but since the JS SDK hides the process a bit, I don't know how for sure how to approach it, if I can at all.

Anyone try this or happen to know how to make it happen?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I am trying to to the exact same thing... You'd have thought that now Soundcloud is a 'freemium' based business model, they would make this easy to do...

Comment: Nope. I haven't checked recently to see if they updated the API to support this. Regardless of their model, you're talking about a situation where there could be multiple MB of data to transfer. It just seems pointless to not have an avenue to upload the file at least directly. Vimeo supports this and it's great. Get an upload ticket, do a PUT against their servers, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible (for everyone).

In the section "*Authenticating without the SoundCloud Connect Screen*" on the following soundcloud API docs page: 
https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#authentication

It says:

> Our Terms of Service specify that you must use the Connect with
>   SoundCloud screen **unless you have made a separate arrangement with us.**

So unless you have a deal with soundcloud, 
there's no way you can 'automatically' let a program upload sounds (or doing any modification to soundcloud whatsoever) without having to authenticate first.

Comment: You're not understanding what I'm talking about. I'm not trying to get access to ANOTHER user's account. I'm using my OWN pro account. But SoundCloud wants me to prompt those other user's to log in rather than giving me a way to upload audio to my account. It's not an unusual thing to do or expect. Soundcloud just doesn't care to support that process.

Comment: I Think I understand the problem though, you want users to do something on behalf of you without having to login somewhere. I am currently trying to let a cronjob do stuff on soundcloud (recreate playlists) with the authentication token (mine) I store in the db good for doing stuff with my soundcloud account. I'll let you know what my findings are, cheers

Comment: Essentially, yes. Sort of a pre-authorization. I don't mind using the server code to get an auth token that I can incorporate into a URL that then is used by the client code in JS to perform a PUT to get the file to the SoundCloud servers. I just don't want to pass all those data bytes (the audio) through my servers if I don't have to.

Comment: @KenLFG I successfully managed to let the server do stuff with my access token in a cronjob. I'm saved! Phew! :) I thought about your problem and think it's not possible to do what you want. The process through- your server should be possible. But with upload of data - as you say - you will also have to deal with the traffic and that's not what you want. If the JS api is used, your accesstoken is exposed, probably bad practice. Besides - when calls come from the js lib, I guess it's easy for the soundcloud servercode to figure out that the accesstoken does not belong to the current user.

Comment: Well, bad in practice but maybe the only way to do what I need (the account isn't being used for anything else). I'd thought about just having a server process negotiate the access token and just drop that down to the page. So, basically handling the handshake to get the access token but then dropping it to the client to use. Still not ideal but could work if your access token cronjob worked...

Comment: I'm curious if it will work. Let us know if you succeed. WHen approaching this be sure to explicit score a 'non-expiring' access token. Cost me some slight headaches. :)

Comment: Thanks. I saw that in the docs and stashed it away in my head when I first ran into it. I knew I'd need that. :)